# How to fix a MySQL server with a full hard drive?

Tags: mysql

Overnight, our MySQL server completely filled the hard drive. Now, I cannot login via phpMyAdmin

```
`Cannot log in to the MySQL server`
```

or via the command line

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

or via `mysqladmin`

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
```

There is one big table I can delete as a temporary fix if I can login to the server, but I can't. How can I login?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the local machine?

Comment: Voted to migrate to dba.se; this isn't a programming question.

Comment: This is probably a question for server fault or dba but if you have physical access try booting to a ubuntu usb and deleting some files manually. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to data directory and manually delete some log files like error, slow or general log to get some space to start the MySQL service.

You can also delete the table if it is myisam engine that you can check if the table has three files with extension (.MYI, .MYD and .frm)

Comment: I see them (`.frm` and `.idb`) under a subdirectory for the database at fault. Can I just delete those two files?

Comment: @gwg: if you take some destructive actions, make sure you take a backup first.